# My IPFS node doesn't seem to be storing data, why is that? I wanna contribute to the network

Tags: ipfs

My IPFS node has been running all day and it's storing 6MiB according to the web UI... how come?

I've set the Gateway address in the config as such:

```
"Gateway": "/ip6/2a01:e34:ecb8:d540:dacb:8aff:fee4:74a0/tcp/8081"
```

And I have started the daemon with `ipfs daemon --writable`, it says it's ready.

The UI says it has discovered about 900 nodes, so why is mine not participating more actively in the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other nodes can't store content into your node automatically. There is public ipfs gateway list somewhere, submit your node to it.

run DHT server

```
ipfs config Routing.Type dhtserver
```

more information here https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/config.md